Pick 3 random Items out of pallet Rack and batch them?
Problem
Hi, in Anylogic I have a pallet system, which I fill with box agents at the beginning. In addition, I have AGVs that are supposed to drive to 3 different boxes on the shelf and take each one with them. Now I'm faced with the problem that it simply starts from the beginning and so the first three boxes are just batched together, but I want them to be random boxes somewhere on the shelf.
Layout
What i have tried
I have already tried to batch agents, but only the first ones are taken. The hold block is there so that I can batch at certain intervals, as otherwise all agents (approx. 150) would run through at once, as they are created 150 times in the source block.
Current function
What i want
I would now like 3 random agents to be batched. Ideally, it would be nice if the AGV first travelled to the individual locations on the shelf and then travelled collectively to the unloading zone, but it is also ok if the batched agents are picked up all at once from one location.
It should then look like this:
What it should look like
However, if I try this, the AGV can no longer pick up the new batched agent with the rackPick, especially as it is no longer on the shelf.
If anyone is familiar with this and knows a good solution, I would be very grateful.
